# Fundamental group of the torus minus a disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

Consider the torus $\mathbb{T}$ given by $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ with vertex $p$ in the square of identifications. Now remove a disk $D$ from it (I based its boundary $c$ on $p$). Then, I get the space given by $aba^{-1}b^{-1}c$. Now, I consider two concentric circumferences and let $\mathbb{T}\setminus D = A\cup B$, where $A$ is the exterior of the smaller one and $B$ the interior of the bigger one. So, $A\cap B$ is an open annulus, which is path connected. Let $x_0\in A\cap B$.

Since $B$ is contractible, $\pi_1(B,x_0)$ is trivial. Since $A\cap B$ is an open annulus, $S^1$ is a deformation retract of it, so $\pi_i(A\cap B,x_0)=\langle\varepsilon_0 | \rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$, where $\varepsilon_0$ is the class of the canonical turn to $S^1$.

Now, notice that $A$ can be retracted with deformation into the boundary of the identification polygon $aba^{-1}b^{-1}c$, which consists in the punctual union of three circumferences $a,b$ and $c$. Then, $\pi_1(A,p)=\langle\alpha_a,\alpha_b,\alpha_c|\rangle\cong F_3$, where $\alpha_a,\alpha_b,\alpha_c$ are the classes of the canonical turns to the circumferences $a,b$ and $c$. But we want to base the fundamental group of $A$ in $x_0$. Consider $\gamma$ and path between $x_0$ and $p$. Let $\varepsilon_1 = [\gamma a\bar{\gamma}]$,$\varepsilon_2 = [\gamma b\bar{\gamma}]$ and $\varepsilon_3 = [\gamma c\bar{\gamma}]$, where $\bar{\gamma}$ denote the path $\gamma$ walked in the other way. Then, $\pi_1(A,x_0)=\langle\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3|\rangle$.

Then, by Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}\setminus D)=\langle\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3 | R_{12}\rangle$, where $R_{1,2}=\{i_{1*}(\varepsilon_0)i_{2*}(\varepsilon_0)^{-1}\}$. Here, $i_{1*}$ and $i_{2*}$ are the homomorphisms induced by the inclusions $i_1:A\cap B\hookrightarrow A$ and $i_2:A\cap B\hookrightarrow B$.

We have that $i_{1*}(\varepsilon_0)=[\gamma ab\bar{a}\bar{b}c\bar{\gamma}]=[\gamma a\bar{\gamma}\gamma b\bar{\gamma}\gamma\bar{a}\bar{\gamma}\gamma\bar{b}\bar{\gamma}\gamma c\bar{\gamma}]=\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_1^{-1}\varepsilon_2^{-1}\varepsilon_3$ and $i_{2*}=1_{\pi_1(B,x_0)}$.

So, with this, we conclude that $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}\setminus D,x_0)=\langle\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3 | \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_1^{-1}\varepsilon_2^{-1}\varepsilon_3\rangle$

Is my approach correct? If it is, is there another way of presenting $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}\setminus D,x_0)$ in terms of abelian or free products?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The fastest way is to note that a torus minus a disk deformation retracts to $S^1 \vee S^1$ so its fundamental group is the free group on two generators. The group presentation you have is exactly that: you have two generators $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ and the third generator is subject to the relation that it's equal to the commutator of the other two. This writes the third "generator" in terms of the other two, so you can reduce this presentation to simply have two generators and no relations.

Comment: Yes! That way is surely faster. Thank you very much for you answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A punctured torus deformation retracts to *figure-eight* (wedge sum of two circles).

[image]